# CUDA Thrust find near neighbor points

Tags: algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing, thrust

In my problem, there are N points in the domain and they are somehow randomly distributed.  For each point I need to find all neighbor points with distance less than a given double precision floating number, DIST.
Is there an efficient way to do this in Thrust?
In serial, I would use a neighborhood table and hope to achieve approximately O(n) instead of naive algorithm of O(n^2).
I have found a thrust example for 2D bucket sort, which is a perfect fit for the first part of my problem. But that is not enough, because for each bucket I need to find all points in the neighbor buckets, and then compute their distances and see if any of them is less than DIST. Finding neighbors and compute distance should be relatively easy, but adding those eligible points to a result array seems really difficult for me to implement in Thrust.
A way to rephrase this particular problem is this -- I have two 2D arrays A1 and A2, the column number represent the index of the 2D bucket and each column have different number of elements that are indices of my points. Each element in column(i) of A1 will form a potential pair with each element in colunm(i) of A2, and all eligible pairs should be recorded to a result array. 
I could use a CUDA kernel and allocating tons of potentially unused memory as a workaround, but that would be the last thing I would want to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find the data structure discussed here useful: https://github.com/jaredhoberock/thrust-workshop/tree/master/more_points

Comment: Jared Hoberock has practically given you the answer and in the linked github page you will find everything you require. I'm just wondering if you need a full tree structure with several levels or you need only one level by partitioning the 2D space in boxes with size related to the minimum inter-element distance you are dealing with. With only one level, for each point, you have to evaluate the distance between each point and only the points within the same box and neighboring boxes. Perhaps a full tree structure will be needed  for implementing multilevel fast multipole like algorithms?

Comment: man you are a life saver! I looked the link you gave and studied quad tree. That will definitely solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Maybe you could write a really brief answer encapsulating the commment so it can be upvoted/accepted and this question can be moved off the unaswered pile.

Answer (score 2):

The full solution is out of the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer, but there's a discussion on how to use Thrust to build a 2D spatial index in this repository:

https://github.com/jaredhoberock/thrust-workshop

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, simpler than creating a quad-tree, is using a **neighborhood matrix**.

First place all your points into a 2D square matrix (or 3D cubic grid, if you are dealing with three dimensions). Then you can run a full or partial spatial sort, so points will became ordered inside the matrix.

Points with small Y could move to the top rows of the matrix, and likewise, points with large Y would go to the bottom rows. The same will happen with points with small X coordinates, that should move to the columns on the left. And symmetrically, points with large X value will go to the right columns.

After you did the spatial sort (there are many ways to achieve this, both by serial or parallel algorithms) you can lookup the nearest points of a given point P by just visiting the adjacent cells where point P is actually stored in the neighborhood matrix.

**If this matrix is placed into texture memory, you can use all the spatial caching from CUDA to have very fast accesses to all neighbors!**

You can read more details for this idea in the following paper (you will find PDF copies of it online): *Supermassive Crowd Simulation on GPU based on Emergent Behavior*.

The sorting step gives you interesting choices. You can use just the even-odd transposition sort described in the paper, which is very simple to implement (even in CUDA). If you run just one pass of this, it will give you a partial sort, which can be already useful if your matrix is near-sorted. That is, if your points move slowly, it will save you a lot of computation.

If you need a full sort, you can run such even-odd transposition pass several times (as described in the following Wikipedia page):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort

There is a second paper from the same authors, describing an extension to 3D and using three passes of the bitonic sort (which is highly parallel, but it is not a spatial sort). they claim it is both more precise than a single even-odd transposition pass and more efficient than a full sort. The paper is *A Neighborhood Grid Data Structure for Massive 3D Crowd Simulation on GPU*.